# Query to add up multiple names from TVP

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of name value pairs like this

Properties
- EmployeeId

My table for employee looks like this:-

```
EmployeeId  FirstName Middle LastName

1           John             Smith

2           Rick      Steve  James

3           Maddy     Y      Angela
```

Now my TVP can contain multiple or single EmployeeId's

I want to add up the full names of all the person in TVP in a single parameter.

i.e.

For eg. If I receive 1 and 3 in TVP

My output should be John Smith, Maddy Y Angela.

Do I need to use cursors in this?

What is the best way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

The Scipt For the TVP is as below:-

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Employee] AS TABLE(    [EmployeeId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL)GO
```

The desired output is the Full Names of Employees in the TVP comma seperated.

Comment: I'm lost. Are you trying to populate a new TVP or are you receiving a TVP with rows 1,3 and you want to just return the name for those employees? What does the properties table have to do with anything?

Comment: A TVP = table valued parameter have to be declared `READONLY` (see Aaron's answer) so this parameter can't be `UPDATE`d. What's the link between "I have a table of name value" and "My table for employee looks like this:" ? Dow you want to return a concatenated string with all names ?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just edited the question to clarify it.
I dont want to select them all but instead add them up to a parameter. All the full names of the Employees in the TVP.
Let me know if that is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a table type like:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TVPTypeName AS TABLE(EmployeeId INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then you can just perform a join:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
  @bar dbo.TVPTypeName READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' 
    + e.FirstName 
    + COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(e.Middle),''), ' ') 
    + e.LastName 
  FROM dbo.Employees AS e
  INNER JOIN @bar AS b
  ON e.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');
END
GO
```

Comment: @vishal did you try it? The output will be a comma-separated list of `first name middle name last name,first name middle name last name,...` as the question seems to request. How it works? Search for the thousands of `FOR XML PATH` answers on this site already.

Comment: No, not yet. I am trying to figure out first what does the last line do. I have never used that.

Comment: @vishal as it implies ("FOR XML"), it converts the output to XML, which you can then use to format as a string.

Comment: Bingle "stuff for xml path" and you will find a host of entries explaining how this works to generate concatenated results

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntArray AS TABLE(IntValue INT PRIMARY KEY);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee(
    EmployeeID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    MiddleName NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee VALUES ('John',NULL,'Smith');
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee VALUES ('Rick','Steve','James');
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee VALUES ('Maddy','Y','Angela');
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CocoJambo(@pEmployee dbo.IntArray READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @Result=ISNULL(@Result,'')+','+FirstName+ISNULL(' '+MiddleName,'')+' '+LastName
    FROM dbo.Employee e INNER JOIN @pEmployee p ON e.EmployeeID=p.IntValue;
    SELECT STUFF(@Result,1,1,'') AS [Result];
END;
GO
-- Test
DECLARE @p dbo.IntArray;
INSERT INTO @p VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO @p VALUES (3);
EXEC dbo.CocoJambo @pEmployee=@p;
/*
Result
-------------------------
John Smith,Maddy Y Angela
*/
```